# Easy css framework with components

Tags: framework, css, design

I'm looking for a css framework that is easy to use and responsive. There should be ready to use components or designs. Moreover, I like clean and "luxurious" designs following the 60-30-10-rule.

For example designs like this:

- https://www.zypsy.com/work/spice-ai
- https://www.bond-agency.io/
- https://www.skyrocket.nz/
- https://orbit.ai/
- https://www.simplesuite.co/
- https://rayco.digital/

As a backend, I will use flask.

Answer (score 1):

There are various CSS Frameworks available, however, it is important to note that you will still need to write your own design to it. A recommended option is to use TailwindCSS, a quite modern and sleek alternative to Bootstrap and other old-fashioned frameworks. Some popular websites built on it include:

- https://www.wealthfront.com/
- https://turbo.build/
- https://column.com/

TailwindCSS is relatively easy to use if you are familiar with CSS Frameworks and provides a lot of pre-built components that you can find on the web. You can even browse through GitHub to find websites that you like and potentially use some of the code.

Comment: Thank you, but I already knew Tailwind.